ServiceProvider in Quartz
Im using quartz and there is method for default DI container such as services.AddQuartz();
But this method has no IServiceProvider parameter or Action<IServiceProvider, IServiceCollectionQuartzConfigurator>
I can configure only QuartzOptions, but what if i want to configure PersistentStore or Cluster settings with my custom settings class using resolved parameter from di container? Quartz options allow you to configure triggers and jobs, but not these parameters.
Any solutions?
